# popup message from an array of alarm times

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a clock on Excel (VBA) and generate an alarm from times that are listed in an array(G4:L28), the alarm should trigger a popup message that would include the corresponding data existing in the adjacent column(f4:f28) and row(G3:L3)

Comment: You can use `Application.OnTime()` for this.

Comment: I keep getting errors, can you please show me the code, I do not have a lot of experience in VBA, thank you Tim

Comment: If you have code then you can update your question,  and state exactly what error you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data looks something like this:

[image]

And you want to set the alarms when the workbook opens, add this code to a new module

**EDIT**

I changed the code to a new module and used global message variable to get around some potential value passing problems.  Now you just need to run SetAlarms at some point to set the alarms.

```
Public AlarmMessage As String

Public Sub displayAlarm()
    MsgBox (AlarmMessage)
End Sub

Sub SetAlarms()
   Dim alarmSheet As Worksheet
   Set alarmSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

   For Each cell In alarmSheet.Range("G4:L4")
       'Set message
       AlarmMessage = alarmSheet.Range("F" & cell.Row).Value

       'Set alarm
       Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=TimeValue(CStr(Format(cell.Value, "hh:mm:ss"))), Procedure:="displayAlarm"
   Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually I used rounded values in the array from the beginning to avoid passing values. this worked, thanks